# User class - 'load' data

Tags: php

```
<?php

class User {

    private $id;
    private $username;

    public function __construct($id = null) {
        $this->id = $id;

        if (!is_null($this->id)) {
            $this->load();
        }
    }

    public function load() {


    }

}

?>
```

In the 'load' method I am going to load all the information from the current user (id) But I wonder how is the best way to load all info. I could grab all data and then just assign all private variables, but I assume there must be another "cheaper" way to get all the data so I can use as such

$this->variable;

And not have to ASSIGN every single data row, I select in the load method. How?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Can you develop about `$this->variable;` and the kind of initialization you want to make ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the following:

- Each User object represents 1 row in your database
- You can retrieve information for your user in an associative array:

  `$user = array('name' => 'John', 'age' => 20);`

Then perhaps using variables variables could be a viable solution in your `load()` method:

```
foreach($user as $key => $userData){
   $this->$$key = $userData; //Note the use of variables variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign multiple variables like this in php:

```
private function getUserData() {
  return array("42", "JohnDoe");
}

public function load() {
  list($this->id, $this->username) = getUserData();
}
```